# rename file names and add water mark on each text file

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio

Lets say, i have 2000 text files which is inside multiple sub-folders, so i want to add those files names beginning with increment numbers and list all files or move to a folder without sub-folder, as a example, i have a file which named **1.casefile-a** inside a sub folder called **Chapter01**, i would like to rename that file with folder name at start like **001.Chapter01.1.casefile-a**. also want to add watermark as some text on each text files content.
**following describe folder directory with subfolders**

```
 Directory of C:\Users\DEV4\Desktop\SAMPLE
12/21/2019  09:31 PM    <DIR>          Chapter 01
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 1.case  file-a.txt
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 2.case  file-b.txt
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 3.case  file-c.txt

12/21/2019  09:32 PM    <DIR>          Chapter 02
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 1.case  file-d.txt
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 2.case  file-e.txt
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 3.case  file-f.txt

12/21/2019  09:32 PM    <DIR>          Chapter 03
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 1.case  file-g.txt
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 2.case  file-h.txt
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 3.case  file-i.txt

12/21/2019  09:33 PM    <DIR>          Chapter 04
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 1.case  file-j.txt
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 2.case  file-k.txt
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 3.case  file-l.txt

12/21/2019  09:33 PM    <DIR>          Chapter 05
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 1.case  file-m.txt
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 2.case  file-n.txt
12/21/2019  09:29 PM                 0 3.case  file-o.txt
```

Following i did,but couldn't complete according to the scenario.

```
        var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\TUTORIALS\");
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\TUTORIALS\", "", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        for (int i = 1; i < fileList.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
               var from = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"E:\TUTORIALS\"+ System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePaths.FirstOrDefault()));
               var to = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"E:\Vid\"+ System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePaths.FirstOrDefault()));

                File.Move(from, to); // Try to move
                Console.WriteLine("Moved"+ filePaths.FirstOrDefault()); // Success
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex); // Write error
            }
        }
```

Comment: please help me to find the solution. thanks.

Comment: What is happening or not happening with that code? How close do you get to the desired output? Also what exactly is the desired output? The starting number of `001.Chapter01.1.casefile-a` - is it a running number, or just the previous start number with 2 zeroes?

Comment: @Christopher moving file to another directory happened,but couldn't rename file's name as described.

Comment: @shantharuban, I think you will need to add another File Move *AFTER* Moving the folder for renaming  
===========
`var currentFileName = to;
var newFileName = i.ToString("000")+"."+Path.GetFileName( Path.GetDirectoryName( currentFileName) )+"."+Path.GetFileName(to);

File.Move(currentFileName,newFileName);`

Comment: @shantharuban Shantharuban, Is it working now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Summary of operations
>
> 1. Move Files (Which you said is working fine)
> 2. Format the naming for your new File
> 3. Rename Files with the desired format

```
string[] filePathscount = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\TUTORIALS\", "", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
for (int i = 1; i < filePathscount.Length; i++)
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\TUTORIALS\", "", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    try
    {
        var from = System.IO.Path.Combine( System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(filePaths.FirstOrDefault()));
        var to = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"E:\Vid\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePaths.FirstOrDefault()));
        var currentFileName = to;
        var newFileName = i.ToString("000") + "." + Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(currentFileName)) + "." + Path.GetFileName(to);
        File.Move(from, to); // Try to move
        File.Move(currentFileName, newFileName); //Renaming aftermoving
        Console.WriteLine("Moved " + filePaths.FirstOrDefault()); // Success
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex); // Write error
    }
}
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault will always select the first file, so either you need to use the index, or the loop is not needed because it does the same thing "n" times.

Comment: oh yea, seeing it now. Since OP mentioned in his comments that moving file works and renaming is not.

Comment: I'm guessing he steps through the first file and stops when it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ron Beyer:yeah, true, i hope that will work after filePaths variable moved inside the for loop. thanks for your help.